# R call java method with List as parameter

Tags: r

How can I pass a list from my R to java function ??
My java function is

```
 public void test(List<String> arg){
 String[][] resultArray =new String[1][1];
 System.out.println(arg.size());
 resultArray[0][0]="hai";
 return resultArray;
```

}

R function is

```
test<-function(params){
obj=.jnew("com/algoTree/ClientElasticSearch/ElasticSearchLoader")
a <- .jnew( "java/util/ArrayList", params )
result=.jcall(obj,"[[Ljava/lang/String;","test",a)
mat=sapply(result,.jevalArray)
mat
```

}

R call

```
temp=c("bloomberg","reuters") 
test(list(temp))
```

But I didn't get the value passed in params in my java code

```
System.out.println(arg.size());  outputs 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will build the list:

```
obj <- new( J("java.util.ArrayList") )
obj$add( "bloomberg" )
obj$add( "reuters" )
obj$size()
# [1] 2
```

I think the problem is with the construction of your `ArrayList`. Which constructor did you want to use ?

Comment: thanks for your reply I changed list to Array then use obj<- .jarray(params)